# Retrieving entries of linked list in relational database

Tags: sql, oracle, linked-list, rdbms

For my project, I implemented linked list with rdbms. The linked list uses rowid column as a pointer, and contains prior, next and owner pointer(from different table).

The simple example would be like this.

```
   CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
   (
       EMP_ID           NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
       OFFICE_CODE      CHAR(2),
       OFF_EMP_prior    ROWID,
       OFF_EMP_next ROWID,
       OFF_EMP_owner    ROWID
   );
```

`{EMP1,(NULL,EMP2,OFF1)} - {EMP2,(EMP1,EMP3,OFF1)} - {EMP3,(EMP2,NULL,OFF1)}`

Now I have to implement a retrieval function like "Find 'nth(integer)' entry of the list which has 'OFF1' as a owner".

This can be simply done by using loop to traverse the linked list. But this requires too many SQL operations for one retrieval. (I know that using sequence number can be another option, but this is the decision made so far.)

Instead, I found `SELECT - CONNECTED BY` in oracle SQL, and tried

```
select * from EMPLOYEE
where OFF_EMP_owner = [OFF_ROWID]
connect by nocycle OFF_EMP_prior = rowid;
```

This query works for retrieving entries of the list, but the order of the result is not as I expected (something like `EMP3-EMP1-EMP2`).

Is it possible to retrieve entries of the linked list and sort them by the order of the list with `SELECT-CONNECT BY'`? Or is there exists more suitable SQL?

Comment: rowid is a bad choice; you should link/connect to the natural or surrogate key. Normally, in (recursive) SQL having a *parent* pointer is possible, but , in most cases, sub-optimal from a modelling point of view.

Comment: It depends which database environment you're on, if it's SQL Server I would suggest common table expression.

Comment: BTW: your *table* doesn't have a primary key, so it isn'n even a table (in the 2NF sense)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from EMPLOYEE
where DEPT_EMPLOYEE_owner = [OWNER_ROWID}
start with OFF_EMP_prior is NULL
connect by OFF_EMP_prior = prior rowid;
```

Solved the problem with the query above. 'prior' should be used instead of nocycle.